# Java Scanner next() method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is from the Java's Scanner next() method explanation:

> This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a
>   previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

How can this method wait for user input to be entered if a call to hasNext() is made? If we call hasNext() and it returns true, we know that there is next token, so how and why the next() method does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the **full** [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) of the method:

> Finds and returns the next **complete token** from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   **delimiter pattern**. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

The `Scanner#hasNext` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--)) may return `true` when there is another token. But it could be possible that the token is not yet considered as **complete** according to the **delimiter pattern** and `Scanner#next` will always block until the the token is complete.

If there is a **complete token** in the `Scanner` then `Scanner#next` will immediately return and **not block**.

---

You can set the **delimiter pattern** by using the `Scanner#useDelimiter` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.util.regex.Pattern-))

If you don't set a specific delimiter pattern than the `Scanner` will use a default pattern which matches **whitespace characters**.

---

As you have asked, **blocked** means that the method waits and does not return until the said event happened.

Consider this:

```
System.out.println("Before");
someBlockingMethod();
System.out.println("After");
```

With

```
public void someBlockingMethod() {
    // Sleep for a second (ignoring exceptions for simplicity)
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

You will see `After` only once `someBlockingMethod()` has returned and this will only happen once the said event occurred. Thus the method **blocks**. In the example the method blocks for one second.

Comment: I don't understand how can this happen when reading console input. Can you provide some sample code? Also what does 'block' actually mean here?

Comment: When reading from the console, without setting a specific delimiter pattern, you will likely not encounter the scenario with `hasNext` `true` but `next` blocking since you always enter at least the *end of input signal* (*newline* when hitting *enter*) when using the console which is considered as **whitespace character** by the `Scanner`.

Comment: Does that happen when the input between delimiters is long or what?

Comment: And how does the blocking affect my program? How will this affect my programming logic when I want to use this method? Or it is only slower?

Comment: Think of the `Scanner` being connected to a resource which is not yet completely available, a `Stream` for example. If the `Stream` delivers the symbols `Hell` but not yet a **delimiter** like **whitespace** or **end of line/stream**, then you don't want to use this as token since a second later a `o<whitespace>` comes. You want to catch `Hello` and not `Hell` and `o`. In that case `hasNext` returns `true` but `next` will block and wait for `o<whitespace>` to come.

Comment: As said, blocking simply means waiting. Your program will not continue execution until the method has **finished**. This is like if you call `Thread.sleep(1000)` to *pause* the program for a second. It also makes sense since you want to wait for the user to finish his input before parsing it.

Comment: So I suppose this can only happen when the input is not buffered, i.e I read character by character. In the other case, the scanner has all the information from the input. Btw, thanks a lot for the great explanation.

Comment: Yeah that is right. If the scanner already has the complete input (and you don't set a specific delimiter) than this will likely not happen. You're welcome.

Comment: Wait, how can the delimiter cause blocking? Whatever the delimiter is, the scanner will see it and can automatically recognize the token.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner#next` doesn't return a string until it has either reached the delimiter being used by the `Scanner` (whitespace is the default delimiter), or it has reached the end of the input stream.

If `hasNext` returns true, it means there is definitely more data in the input stream, but it may still need to block until it reaches the delimiter/EOF.

Comment: I still don't understand how can this happen when reading console input. Also, what does 'block' mean in this context, because I'm afraid I understand the meaning incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: @LearningMath "Block" means wait. Nothing will happen on the thread until the hardware has finished retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you debug the following code, you will see that, actually, it is hasNext() method that is blocking and waiting for user input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String s = scanner.next();
}
```

That's because there is a blocking step inside hasNext():

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    ensureOpen();
    saveState();
    while (!sourceClosed) {
        if (hasTokenInBuffer())
            return revertState(true);
        readInput(); //THIS IS WAITING FOR USER INPUT
    }
...
```

In case of console input, hasNext() waits till a complete token is entered and returns true, then subsequent next() invocation doesn't block.

In case of non-console input, hasNext() returns true even if there is not complete token, and subsequent next() invocation blocks and waits for complete token.